# Connect LAMP server on Azure to a websocket server

Tags: linux, azure, websocket, webserver, lamp

I have a LAMP server which communicates with a web socket server, both on different Linux machines. Using them in a local network works. Now, I want to put only the LAMP server on Azure (Linux Virtual Machine) and continue to communicate with the web socket server. How can I solve this issue? I was thinking to use SSH tunnel. Is it the right way to proceed with Azure? How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I understand your architecture...

- Does your LAMP "server" talk to your WebSocket server using ws://?  If so, you don't need some sort of tunnel.  That's one of the benefits of the WS protocol; its web-friendly.

or

- Does your LAMP "server" talk to your WebSocket server via TCP for some reason?  If so... why not use the WS protocol?  Or if you really need TCP, then you would need some sort of tunnel, either SSH or something like [Kaazing KWIC on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/kaazing/kaazing-kwic/).

Full disclosure.  I work for Kaazing.

Comment: Maybe my question was not totally clear. I have my LAMP server (PC1) on the cloud that can talk to a websocket server (PC2). From a third machine (PC3), on a third network, I want to use a browser to navigate web pages on PC1 with the possibility to execute some ws communication with PC2. Today, I solved using the tunnel. Without, it does not work.

Comment: To be clear (I wish I could draw here), you log onto PC3, fire up a browser which then connects to a LAMP server (Apache specifically) on PC1.  PC1 then relays the connection to PC2 which is a WS server.  If this is correct, this is a typical (albeit simplistic) WS topology.  Does your WebSocket server support Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing?  You may need to open access to PC1.  Which WS server are you using?